# Where can I set if debug-symbols are included in a IntelliJ IDEA build?

Tags: intellij-idea

Where can I set if debug-symbols are included in the build of a Java-application when building with IntelliJ IDEA 2016.2.5?
The documentation says here - https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.2/configuring-debugger-options.html - that there is a preferences dialog-box under project-structure. But with my IDEA, there isn't such dialog box.

The project structure dialog-box looks like this on my computer:
[image]

Thanks in advance,
Bonita

Answer (score 0):

The "Settings/Preferences dialog box" is the generally IDE settings dialog, not the specific project settings dialog.

You can find this dialog in the main menu bar under *File > Settings* (and then *Build, Execution and Deployment* > *Java Compiler*), or by  pressing `Ctrl+Alt+S`.

Comment: Thanks, but I found that the setting under Settings / "Build; Execution, Deployment" / "Java Compiler" / "Generate debugging info" is project-specifig although it looks like it is a global setting.
The items which can be found in the settings-dialog are partitially global, partitially project-specific - very confusing. F.e. the code-style settgins are global.